# Remove leading spaces from strings in DataFrame column of lists

Tags: python, list, strip

Assuming an existing df with a column containing lists of countries...

```
x = df['Countries'][0]
x
```

['Australia',
' Brazil',
' Canada',
' China']

We see that other than the first country, each next country has a leading space that is preventing a string comparison further down my script. I am trying to use lstrip() to strip away the spaces for each list in the column.

```
y = []

for eachRow in df['Countries']:
     for country in eachRow:
          country = country.lstrip()
    y.append(country)
y
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

I'm sure there's a simpler way.

Comment: `df['Countries'] = df['Countries'].str.strip()`

Comment: @It_is_Chris not quite, I guess, it's a series containing lists of strings, not a series containing strings (unless pandas is doing more magic than I think).

Comment: @mkrieger1 ah you are correct. I missed the `[0]` at the end of `x = df['Countries'][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a lambda function with map and str.strip

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': [['Australia', ' Brazil', ' Canada', ' China']]})

df['Countries'] = df['Countries'].apply(lambda x: list(map(str.strip, x)))

print(df['Countries'][0]) # -> ['Australia', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'China']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas.str method. It works with nan. Just do:
`df['columns']=df['column'].str.strip()` as said above. If you got nans it will still work:

```
paises = pd.DataFrame()
paises['name']= ["1" ," Argentina", "Brazil ", " Mexico "]
paises.loc[0,'name'] = np.nan

for i in paises.name:
    if type(i) == type(paises.iloc[0,0]):
        print("Wrong name")
    elif type(i) == type(paises.iloc[1,0]):
        print(f"Name: {i} ->> Number of characters {len(i)}")

paises['name'] = paises['name'].str.strip()
print("\n---------------------------------\n")

for i in paises.name:
    if type(i) == type(paises.iloc[0,0]):
        print("Wrong name")
    elif type(i) == type(paises.iloc[1,0]):
        print(f"Name: {i} ->> Number of characters {len(i)}")
```

Wrong name

Name:  Argentina ->> Number of characters 10

Name: Brazil  ->> Number of characters 7

Name:  Mexico  ->> Number of characters 8

---

Wrong name

Name: Argentina ->> Number of characters 9

Name: Brazil ->> Number of characters 6

Name: Mexico ->> Number of characters 6